# How do I connect to Ubuntu Server on the local machine from Ubuntu Desktop?

Tags: networking, server, permissions, ssh, virtualbox

Currently I am running an Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop on a virtual machines in Windows. My goal is to install Snipe-IT and for this I need to make some configurations on the server. But it seems that I am not able to connect to the server machine from the desktop machine. I am fairly new to servers and troubleshooted a lot but editing the sshd_config file didn't word. I try using ssh to login into the server with usernameServer@127.0.0.1 but password authentification returns "permission denied, please try again". And also using usernameServer@12.0.2.15 returns the same error. How can I establish a connection between the Ubuntu Server and Ubuntu Desktop running on the same local machine?

Comment: The `127.0.0.1` address points to “self”, so `usernameServer@127.0.0.1` will try to connect to itself, which isn’t what you’re looking for. The simplest way is to use a “Bridged Network” setting in VirtualBox and set the move to “Allow All”. This will put the VMs on the local network with externally-accessible IPs.

Comment: From further information provided in your response to a deleted answer, seems like you have a networking issue on your VM Host. Not an Ubuntu-related problem.

Comment: Yes I read about the bridged network and it seems like a virtualization issue. Would it help to setup a proper virtualization between the virtual machines? Like a virtual private network. How would you do the setup?